# Scraping specific data from each row in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping data from a web site and I am trying to get specific data. Here I am trying to get the colors in each row of `soup.find('div', class_ = "color-swatch-row type-swatch-image")`:

[image: This is part of the HTML code]

Here's the website: https://www.hoka.com/en/us/mens-
everyday-running-shoes/rincon-3/1119395.html

This is what I tried:

```py
for row in soup.find('div', class_ = "color-swatch-row type-swatch-image"):
    color = row.find('title')
    print(color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to switch the last line for:

```
print(color.text)
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).